# Excel IF THEN formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Test paper of 30 multiple choice questions
128 students.
I want to create spreadsheet where I can enter their choice of answer (eg: a,b,c,d,e) under the relevant question column with the formula changing the entry to 1 if correct and 0 if incorrect.
I did it years ago but can't remember how

Comment: =if(B2="a",1,0) write it where you want the result, B2 is the answer and instead of "a" write the right answer (a,b,c,d,e)

Comment: "with the formula changing the entry" - you need to use macro for that. There is no formula which would overwrite data which you've manually entered in a cell.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is a site to ask specific questions after you have attempted something and have run into issues. Your question lacks details of what you have done so far. It reads more like you want us to do it for you. Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried and what formula you are working with.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a **three column** approach.
Use column **A** for the student's answer.
Use column **B** for the correct answer and in **C1** enter the formula:

```
=IF(A1=B1,1,0)
```

and copy down:

[image]

This can be generalized to create a multi-student report.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your Excel worksheet set up like

```
Question      Answer      Student Response      Score
```

The question is the question or question number, the answer is the actual answer, the student response is the student answer and the score is if it's right or not

So, it would look like

```
Question            Answer      Student Response      Score
What happens if....    A             C                 0
What happens if....    D             D                 1
```

Simply, in Column D (the score), you have

```
=IF(B2 = C2, 1, 0)
```

At the bottom of the Score column, you can simply SUM up the results